# ASP.NET MVC - Default Layout to Full Screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, css

New to the .net framework, mvc and visual studio so this may be an easy question. For whatever reason, despite hours of trial and error, I cannot get my views to take up the full page when using the default layout that is created with a new MVC application.

I’ve tried various css tricks to expand elements to 100% height and what not but have had no such luck. Is there a way to do this using bootstrap? If not, any suggestions as to how to do this without effecting bootstrap?

I’ve been able to get the width to span the whole page by implementing the "row" class. The height component of this remains elusive.

**_layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Crestwood Weather</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Crestwood Weather Viewer", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")            </li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Crestwood Midstream Partners LP</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

It appears the HTML and Body of the view it is limited to something in the layout constraining it to half the height of the page. Even when manipulating HTML and Body Tags, The content still displays as bellow.

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use boostrap class "container-fluid" to display on a full screen.

Answer (score 0):

In Content directory there is a site.css file, in this file modify max-width: 960px;

Comment: Which Element? And why a width? And why 960px? Tried that on HTML, and Body tags with no luck.

Comment: on what tag in the css?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

write like this code in javascript..

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ResizeContentContainer();

    });

    window.onresize = ResizeContentContainer;

    function ResizeContentContainer() {

        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        $(".body-content").outerHeight(windowHeight + "px");
    }
</script>
```

This will add height according to the window to the body-content and when you re-size it will automatically calculate the height of your body-content.

Comment: No luck here either. Using google developers tools I can confirm that the body did in fact expand to the full height of the screen, however the content remains at about half height.

Answer (score 0):

was having the same issue finally figured out,
simply add this in your _layout ->

```
<style>
html{
height:100%;
}
body{
height:100%
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**